# Couldn't open file yolov3_custom_last.weights when trying to run darknet detection

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, yolo

I've been trying to use YOLO (v3) to implement and train an object detection of Tank with `OpenImage` dataset.
I have tried to get help from [this tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Mh2HP_Mfxoao6qNFbhfV3u28tG8jAVGk) and my code pretty much looks like it.
Also I'm using Google Colab  and Google Drive services.
everything is going fine through my program. But I hit an error at the final step when I'm running the `darknet` to train detection.

```
!./darknet detector train "data/obj.data" cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg "darknet53.conv.74" -dont_show
```

after 100 iterations, when it's trying to save the progress in the backup folder I've addressed in `obj.data` file, I get the following error:

```
Saving weights to /content/drive/My\Drive/YOLOv3/backup/yolov3_custom_last.weights
Couldn't open file: /content/drive/My\Drive/YOLOv3/backup/yolov3_custom_last.weights
```

at first, I thought I made a mistake in using the address; So, I tried checking the address by using ls command

```
!ls /content/drive/My\Drive/YOLOv3/backup/
```

and the result was an empty folder (However, not an error meaning I've written the address correctly and that it is accessable in my google drive).

Here are contents of data.object file:

```
classes = 1
train = data/train.txt
valid = data/test.txt
names = data/obj.names
backup = /content/drive/My\ Drive/YOLOv3/backup
```

also I've made required changes in config file so I don't think that the problem is about that. But just to make sure here are the changes I've made in my `yolov3.cfg` file:

1. Fist of all we will comment lines 3 and 4 (batch, subdivisions) to unset testing mode
2. We will uncomment lines 6 and 7(batch, subdivisions) to set to training mode
3. We change our `max_batches` value to **2000 * number_of_classes** (if there's one class like our case, set to 4000)
4. We change our step tuple-like values to 80%, 90% value of our max_baches value. In this case it will be 3200, 3600.
5. For **all** YOLO layers and convoloutional layers before them, changed the `classes` value to number of classes, In this case 1, and change the value of `filters` according to following formula(In this case, 18)

**Formula for conv layers filters value:** (number_of_classes + 5)*3

I searched the error and found [this issue](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/416) on Github.
However, I tried the following methods recommended there and the problem is still the same:

1. Removing and recreating the `backup` folder
2. Tried to adding the line   `backup = backup` in my `yolo.data` file in folder `.cfg` but there was no such file in cfg folder.
3. Creating an empty `yolov3_custom_last.weights` in backup folder

The other solutions mentioned in this issue was about when you are running YOLO on your PC and not google Colab.
Also, here my tree structure of the folder YOLOv3 which is stored in my Google Drive My Drive(main folder).

```
YOLOv3
        darknet53.conv.74
        obj.data
        obj.names
        Tank.zip
        yolov3.weights
        yolov3_custom.cfg
        yolov3_custom1.cfg.txt
```

So, I'm kinda stuck and I have no idea what could fix this. I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: when you first connect your drive to colab, drive folders acts like they are compressed. I don't know why but after your code acceses a folder for the first time in the drive it is really slow,  you can try copying a file in to backup folder for this first access thing and maybe that solves it.

Comment: Did you find any fix?

Comment: @Tul Yes. Actually the problem wasn't from me but from yolov3 developers! Apparently as much as I figured in their docs, they are not handling space in directory quite well.
So I created a virtual address which does not have space like `My Drive` has.
P.S: As you know My Drive folder is already there in your google drive so you can't actually rename it.

here is the code you can use to achieve this:
`!ln -s /content/drive/My\ Drive/ /mydrive`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem with changing the local drive address with `ln` command.
The problem wasn't from my code rather from the way way yolov3 developers were handling `space` in directory addresses! Apparently as much as I figured in their docs, they are not handling space in directory quite well.
So I created a virtual address which does not have space like My Drive has.
P.S: As you know My Drive folder is already there in your google drive so you can't actually rename it.
Here is the code you can use to achieve this:

`!ln -s /content/drive/My\ Drive/ /mydrive`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error on my Windows 10, and I think I managed to fix it. All I had to do was move my "weights" folder (with my yolov3.weights inside), closer to the .exe file, which was in the "x64" folder, in my case. After that, the error stopped appearing and the app was able to predict the test image normally.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. Actually that was not the problem. I have posted the answer for this.
 Kind regards.